# Java - How to save users input into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a battleship game using classes. The game first asks the name for 2 players then asks the player for the 2 points to set the ship. players go back and forth picking points till the a ship is sunken and displays the winner.

Where i am stuck on is trying to save those points into the 2D array with the corresponding players name. I want to use one point for both players just to make it short. I will appreciate any suggestions.

runBattleship main class: inputs and outputs

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

Players p1 = new Players();
Players p2 = new Players();

Grid px = new Grid();
Grid py = new Grid();

System.out.print("Welcome to Battleship game");

System.out.println("");
System.out.print("Player 1 enter name: ");
p1.setName(keyboard.next());

System.out.print("Player 2 enter name: ");
p2.setName(keyboard.next());

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Player 1 select point x and y (5x5 grid)");
px.setPointX(keyboard.nextInt());
py.setPointY(keyboard.nextInt());
```

Players class: getters and setters for players name and calls object from Grid to get points.

```
String name;
int pointX, pointY;

Players(){
    name = "";
}
public Players(String name, Grid pointX, Grid pointY){
    this.name = name;
    this.pointX = pointX.getPointX();
    this.pointY = pointY.getPointY();
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Grid class: getters and setters for the points user inputs

```
Ship[][] board = new Ship[5][5];
int pointX, pointY;

public int getPointX() {
    return pointX;
}

public void setPointX(int pointX) {
    this.pointX = pointX;
}

public int getPointY() {
    return pointY;
}

public void setPointY(int pointY) {
    this.pointY = pointY;
}
```

Ship class: where i plan to save the ships if its the right place to do so

```
String name;
int px, py;

public void placeShipAt(Grid pointX, Grid pointY, Players name){
    this.name = name.getName();
    this.px = pointX.getPointX();
    this.py = pointY.getPointY();


}
```

Comment: You could invest little time to learn `Map`, so that you don't do complex arrangement in arrays, but you can still do it anyway :).

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone Map? is that an easier to use? i've never heard of it

Comment: Like `Map<String NameOrId,  Integer AnyOfHis2Data [][]>` ....,

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone so that would be in the main class and use an iterator right?